# Create a sublist without letter "b"

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list from a list, the new list contain only '1' '2' without b letter

```
list = [b'117', b'116', b'115', b'114']
```

**i want a new list like that**

```
newlist = ['117', '116', '115', '114']
```

Comment: you want output as `list = ['117', '116', '115', 114']`?

Comment: The `b` isn't part of the string, it indicates that it's a `bytes` object rather than a string.

Comment: `newlist = [x.decode() for x in lst]`

Comment: yes it's bytes, and yes @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's worked, the list don't contains b anymore but when i use " pattern_uid = re.compile('\d+ \(UID (?P<uid>\d+)\)')" for the list in python2 it works. and in pyhton3 it doesn't work

Comment: use a b prefix in your pattern.